# where to put na.rm=T in my apply function

Tags: r

I have three populations for which I am calculating allele frequency using the following code. I have made a matrix to store the allele frequencies

```
M=matrix(NA,nrow(mydata),3,) #3 populations
colnames(M)=c("pop1","pop2","pop3")
```

and then calculate for each population using

```
#population 1
M[,1]=(apply(mydata[,which(colnames(mydata)=="pop1")],
1,function(x) sum(x)/(length(x)*2))
```

Where would I put na.rm=T so that I don't get an error due to the NAs in my data? I have tried

```
M[,1]=(apply(mydata,na.rm=T[,which(colnames(mydata)=="pop1")],
1,function(x) sum(x)/(length(x)*2))
```

but I get an error back (incorrect number of dimensions)

Comment: try within the `sum(x, na.rm=T)`, as that's the only function you're using that has a `na.rm` argument. However, I think you have other issues in your `apply(...)`

Comment: thanks, I just tried that and didn't get an error back, will run the entire dataset now and see how it goes 
edit - thanks @Symbolix , worked perfectly :)

Comment: you're welcome; I've written it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sum()` function is the one that takes a `na.rm` argument

see

```
sum
function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
```

So you'll need the `na.rm = TRUE` inside your `sum(x, na.rm=T)` function.